# How to write a function in Alloy that returns a subset

Tags: alloy

How do I write a function in Ally that returns a subset of the parameter:

```
fun subset( s : set univ ) : set univ {..}
```

I can write a predicate:

```
pred subset( disj a, b : set univ ) { b in a }
```

However, a function would be nicer to read but I am not sure how to put constraints on the return value?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any clean way to do it.

A dirty hack to achieve your goal would be to differentiate univ elements by, e.g., ranking them. To do so,  I'd introduce an arbitrary signature in which a rank relation is defined, associating an integer to each univ element.

Then, returning an arbitrary subset would simply consist in removing from a given set elements who have e.g. the highest rank.

```
fun subset( s : set univ ) : set univ {
   let maxRank= max[diff.rank[s]] |
      s - diff.rank.maxRank 
}

one sig diff{
  // remove -Int if you plan to use your subset function on sets of Int as well
  rank : (univ -Int) -> one Int
}
```

Comment: I am glad it was not as simple as the previous problem :-) (Should alloy have a way to 'name' the return value just like we have the this name? like `fun subset( s : set univ ) : set univ { return in s and return != s }`. Or is that stupid? ) Anyway, thanks for the help

Comment: It's certainly not stupid but the challenge in expressing what we want with functions is to find an expression whose value given a set of univ s would be a subset of s.
"return in s and return != s" at the end of the day is a boolean expression so it won't possibly work.

Comment: Any success applying  my little hack ? :-)

Comment: I decided to go for the predicate. My primary goal is to create something that is readable, even by lay people. Functions/predicates help to provide a name to what's happening. However, when they look in the function/predicate it should still be understandable. Your solution looks very clever but would take away the readability.
b) The idea of the `return ...` idea was that the `return` would stand in for the result. So even though the expression is boolean it should return `return`, a value for which this expression is true.